# Explained date command syntax %

Tags: date, coreutils

Why does `date +%Y%m%d -s "20081127"` set the date to 2008 (year), 11 (month) and 27 day, but `date +%Y -s "2008"` sets the clock to 20:08?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the presence of the `-s` flag, I'm assuming that you describe the GNU `date` command (part of the GNU coreutils set of utilities).

The format string only affects the output of `date`. The utility does not use the supplied format string to parse the given date/time string.

GNU `date` has quite complex rules for parsing dates. You may find these in the `info date` or `info coreutils` documentation under the "[Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats)" heading.

Especially the text under "[Pure numbers in date strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Pure-numbers-in-date-strings.html#Pure-numbers-in-date-strings)" would be interesting to you:

> The precise interpretation of a pure decimal number depends on the context in the date string.
>
> If the decimal number is of the form *yyyymmdd* and no other calendar date item (see Calendar date items) appears before it in the date string, then *yyyy* is read as the year, *mm* as the month number and *dd* as the day of the month, for the specified calendar date.
>
> **If the decimal number is of the form *hhmm* and no other time of day item appears before it in the date string, then *hh* is read as the hour of the day and *mm* as the minute of the hour, for the specified time of day.** *mm* can also be omitted.
>
> If both a calendar date and a time of day appear to the left of a number in the date string, but no relative item, then the number overrides the year.

Note that this applies to *all* utilities in the GNU coreutils collection that are able to parse dates, not just GNU `date`.